# Recursive Traverse of Binary Tree Not Terminating At Return Statement

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I have created a class that populates a binary tree with morse code.  Where traversing to the left signifies a DOT and traversing to the right signifies a DASH.  Everything was going great until I am writing an encode method to convert a alpha character into a morse code string. The method should recursively do a preorder traverse of the tree(creating a string of the morse code along the way) until it finds a target character and then returns that string.

However, for some reason my recursion won't terminate on my base case.  It just keeps running the entire traverse.  I attached my code for the method below.  Why does the return statement at in the if statement not trigger and end the method?

Sorry if this is ambiguous, but I didn't want to post 300 lines of code for my entire project when someone smarter than I would notice the problem right off.

Thanks for any help

```
    //wrapper class
    //@parameter character is the character to be encoded
    //@return return the morse code as a string corresponding to the character

    public String encode(char character){

        return encode(morseTree, character, "");


    }


    //@Parameters tree is the binary tree is the tree to be searched, 
    //element is the target character trying to be foudn, s is the string being used to build the morse code
    //@return returns the morse code that corresponds to the element being checked

    public String encode(BinaryTree<Character> tree, char target, String s){


        if(tree.getData() == target){  //if the data at the current tree is equal to the target element
            //return the string that is holding the morse code pattern for this current traversal
            return s;
        }else{
            if(tree.getLeftSubtree() != null){
                    //Traverse the left side, add a DOT to the end of a string to change the morse code
                    encode(tree.getLeftSubtree(), target, s + DOT);
            }

            if(tree.getRightSubtree() != null){
                    //Traverse the left side, add a DOT to the end of a string to change the morse code
                    encode(tree.getRightSubtree(), target, s + DASH);
            }
        }

        //The code should never get this far!
        return s;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your calls in the `else` block don't return - they probably should, like this:

```
if (tree.getLeftSubtree() != null) {
   // Traverse the left side, add a DOT to the end of a string to
   // change the morse code
   return encode(tree.getLeftSubtree(), target, s + DOT);
}

if (tree.getRightSubtree() != null) {
    // Traverse the left side, add a DOT to the end of a string to
    // change the morse code
    return encode(tree.getRightSubtree(), target, s + DASH);
}
```

However, what do you want to happen if both the left and right subtrees are null? And if they're both *non-null*, what do you want to return?

Note that just because your base call already returned, that only returns for *that single call* - not all the other calls in the stack. Recursing doesn't *replace* the stack frame with the new call - it just adds *another* stack frame<sup>1</sup>. Returning from that new stack frame just gets you back to where you were.

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, I know about tail recursion. Let's not confuse things though.

Comment: What I want it to return is the morse code for the target character.  I'm building a string that represents that code with s and DOT or DASH on each step of the recursion.  Though I thought the recursion would stop when I did the return.  I guess not.

Comment: Ok, it does seem that I need I need the return statement in the else blocks, but I did something else wrong somewhere in there because it is not getting out of my left side traversal.  I need to trace my code a bit to see where I went wrong, though your tip about adding the return statement seems to be pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Penn: It stops when you return from the first method call - the return statement when you're already 10 stack frames down doesn't pop the stack all the way up.